# PostgreSQL: Text to JSONB - total size exceeds the maximum

Tags: c, postgresql

I've imported a JSON array in a text field and want to convert this to JSONB.

I get the following error

> SQL Error [54000]: ERROR: total size of jsonb array elements exceeds the maximum of 268435455 bytes
>     ERROR: total size of jsonb array elements exceeds the maximum of 268435455 bytes
>     ERROR: total size of jsonb array elements exceeds the maximum of 268435455 bytes

The `pg_column_size()` function returns a size of 59,596,497.

The size of the JSON data was 200 MB on disk before I used the COPY command to import the data into the Postgres database.

**How can I get around this? E.g. by calculating the resulting size from my JSON file on disk before importing?**

### Update: I found the source code for the class that is throwing this exception. Maybe someone with expertise in `C` can have a look at that.

- [GitHub - jsonb_util.c - Line 1569](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb_util.c#L1569)
- [GitHub - jsonb_util.c - Line 1589](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb_util.c#L1589)

Comment: 200MB in Text is much more in jsonb format

Comment: You can calculate the size with `select pg_column_size(to_jsonb('[YOUR DATA]'::text))`.

Comment: The actual size is about `200MB*1,28`

Comment: Thanks! Why not post this as an answer so i can accept that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Text data will be larger when being saved in postgres tables.
You can get an approximate value: `DATA_SIZE*1,28` [2nd Quadrant](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/jsonb-type-performance-postgresql-9-4/).

Also, before loading your data `select pg_column_size(to_jsonb('[DATA]'::text))` will give you a hint of your expected size.