# How to export jsonb column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

There is a jsonb field named data in my postgresql table.
I want to export the data column use the sql like below

```
copy (select data from table) to '/tmp/data.json';
```

But when I use python and jq to load this json file, there are always some errors.Such as

```
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 162 (char 161) # python
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 185 # jq
```

So what is the right way to export this jsonb field?

Answer (score 0):

You are saving invalid json file, try this:

```sql
COPY (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(data)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
) TO '/tmp/data.json';
```

Comment: Thanks. But postgresql throw a error: total size of jsonb array elements exceeds the maximum of 268435455 bytes.
And I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48931558/postgresql-text-to-jsonb-total-size-exceeds-the-maximum.
But I've no idea how to solve this.

Comment: You can post process your output file after
`copy (select data from table) to '/tmp/data.json';`
via command
`sed '$s/$/\]/; 1s/^/[/; s/}$/},/' /tmp/data.json > /tmp/data.json` then you will get valid json file

Comment: It still doesn't work in python and jq.